# How to prevent Vim from automatically indenting new lines?

Tags: vimrc, indentation

I use vim to edit a lot of latex files using vim 7.4. Some trick of the syntax
indenting annoys me and interferes with my intentions. Particularly, the automatic indentation during the addition of a line. I tried to remove this by

```
:set noautoindent
```

but it produces no effect. Which of the many options is working against my desires?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

After examining similar questions, I've found the solution is to `:set nosmartindent`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this just recently and my solution was different.
My vim setup was:

```
:set
--- Options ---
  background=dark     history=200         langnoremap       nomodeline            ruler               scrolloff=5         ttimeout            ttyfast             wildmenu
  display=truncate    incsearch         nolangremap           nrformats=bin,hex   scroll=37           showcmd             ttimeoutlen=100     ttymouse=sgr
  backspace=indent,eol,start
```

if you pay attention, backspace has indent on it...

setting it differently (just removing the **indent**)

```
:set backspace=eol,start
```

solved the issue

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Your proposed change should only affect pressing Backspace, though, right? So not really "adding a new line" as in the question.

Comment: Actually, when I see "Particularly, the automatic indentation during the addition of a line." by OP, i believe vim backspace would be this "addition of a line"

Comment: With this, my backspace doesn't remove indents anymore