# Preventing cursor from indenting after a previously indented line

Tags: neovim, indentation

I'm using neovim and a `init.lua` file.

In what follows `X` will indicate the cursor:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(iX
```

Then I press `o`:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i)
    X
```

Then I press backspace:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i)
X
```

So far so good.

Now I press `o`:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i)

    X
```

I don't want this.

I want:

```
for i in range(1,5):
    print(i)
vim -Nu NONE --cmd "filetype plugin indent on"
X
```

After reading [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10779/how-to-prevent-vim-from-automatically-indenting-new-lines), I set `:set nosmartindent` without success.

Note that `indentexpr=nvim_treesitter#indent()`.

Comment: I have tried to set `autoindent`, which should "Copy indent from current line when starting a new line",but I obtain the same result, although there is no indent on the previous line (and so the cursor should be at the start).

Comment: can't reproduce it, what is your setup?

Comment: Possibly related: what is the value of the `indentkeys` option?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation for python is set with `set indentexpr`, if you have:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in your configuration, then upon opening python file your `indentexpr` would be set to `python#GetIndent(v:lnum)` -- function that calculates indent for a current line.

With `vim -Nu NONE --cmd "filetype plugin indent on" test.py` it works just how you would like it to work.

[image: asciicast]

Comment: I didn't understand. `python#GetIndent(v:lnum)` is good? so I should set it to this value? What I have to do?

Comment: @robertspierre, it should be set automatically if you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your configuration.

Comment: I have `indentexpr=nvim_treesitter#indent()` (I didn't set it to this value manually. So I think the treesitter plugin set it?). I'm also using a init.lua, not init.vim.

Comment: In other words, try command `vim -Nu NONE --cmd "filetype plugin indent on" test.py` and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: @robertspierre, oh. You should have specified you use neovim in the first place.

Comment: sorry for that [comments must be 15 characters length]

Comment: BTW no, with this command the backspace will not even delete the indent in insert mode. And `:set backspace?` returns `backspace=`.

Comment: @robertspierre, sure, because this command runs vim without user configuration + what you have provided with `--cmd` flag. Just to make sure nothing in your configuration is in charge of that unwanted behavior.

Comment: Anyways this is something with treesitter and hopefully ppl who use neovim will be able to help you.